adduser with german letters (ä ö ü) in name not possible
I have a problem when trying to add a user (jörg) to my lubuntu 22.04. adduser with German letters (ä ö ü) in name not possible.
alex@Guilmon:~$ echo $LANG
de_DE.UTF-8

Errormessage translated to english
alex@Guilmon:~$ sudo adduser jörg
[sudo] Passwort für alex: 
adduser: To avoid problems, the username should consist only of
letters, digits, underscores, periods, at signs and dashes, and not start with
a dash (as defined by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001). For compatibility with Samba
machine accounts $ is also supported at the end of the username

Can I work around this?

Probably not. Many programs, some of them old (or very old) use the password file (man 5 passwd;man getent) or getent to translate the UID to a userid. Not all support UTF-8.

this stack question has some interesting aspects to it which to my mind answers the question admirably. Be careful what you wish for... This might be best addressed on Meta to be honest.

I don't think IEEE Standard 1003.1-2001 allows international characters based on my initial perusal of it.  Which is why it doesn't permit it and says "to avoid problems..." in the adduser tool.

Okay then i take joerg instead. This should work. Thanks.
